# At Vis.js, timeline, refresh display on change data

Tags: javascript, timeline, vis.js

i have set a html-form in this text box i change the title, content, start- and end-time. By a click on 'okay'-button change the dataitem.
How can i refresh the timline?

Code from onlclick-Button

```
    var onClickEditOkay = function () {
    if (selItemNr != null){
        var start = new Date(dummyDate);
        var sh = tbStart.value.split(":");
        start.setHours(parseInt(sh[0]));
        start.setMinutes(parseInt(sh[1]));
        var end = new Date(dummyDate);
        sh = tbEnd.value.split(":");
        end.setHours(parseInt(sh[0]));
        end.setMinutes(parseInt(sh[1]));
        timeline.itemsData._data[selItemNr].start = start;
        timeline.itemsData._data[selItemNr].end = end;
        timeline.itemsData._data[selItemNr].title = tbTitle.value;
        timeline.itemsData._data[selItemNr].content = tbContent.value;      
        timeline.redraw();
    }
};
```

The values of item is correct set also the start and end, but the timline shows nothing change.

regards Mario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have found the solution:

The javascrtipt class store the _data.id into cuItemId
and in the OnClick function i call timeline.itemdData.update().

```
var onClickEditOkay = function () {
    if (selItemNr != null){
        var start = new Date(dummyDate);
        var sh = tbStart.value.split(":");
        start.setHours(parseInt(sh[0]));
        start.setMinutes(parseInt(sh[1]));
        var end = new Date(dummyDate);
        sh = tbEnd.value.split(":");
        end.setHours(parseInt(sh[0]));
        end.setMinutes(parseInt(sh[1]));
        timeline.itemsData.update({id: cuItemId, start: start,end: end, title: tbTitle.value, content: tbContent.value});
    }
};
```

That works fine.
regards Mario